# How do I resolve Vue undefined error when I use Proxy

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, undefined

I am new to VueJS and following Brad's Crash course. However, I run into this error whenever I change to proxy. Apart from variable_names that I changed, I did not do anything different from what he did.

Here is my Vue.app code

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <Header @toggle-add-health="toggleAddHealth" title= "Health Tracker" :showAddHealth="showAddHealth" />
  <div v-show="showAddHealth">
    <AddHealthParameter  @add-health="addHealth"  />
  </div>
  
  <Health @toggle-reminder="toggleReminder" @delete-health_parameter="deleteHealth" :health_parameters="health_parameters" />
</div>
 
</template>

<script>
 import Header from './components/Header'
 import Health from './components/Health'
 import AddHealthParameter from './components/AddHealthParameter'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components:{
    Header,
    Health,
    AddHealthParameter,

  },
  data() {
    return {
      health_parameters: [],
      showAddHealth: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleAddHealth() {
      this.showAddHealth = !this.showAddHealth

    },
    addHealth(health_parameter) {
      this.health_parameters = [...this.health_parameters, health_parameter]
    },
    deleteHealth(id){
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete? ')){
      this.health_parameters = this.health_parameters.filter((health_parameter) => health_parameter.id !== id)
      }

    },
    toggleReminder(id){
      this.health_parameters = this.health_parameters.map((health_parameter) => health_parameter.id === id ? {...health_parameter, reminder: !health_parameter.reminder} : health_parameter)
      
    },
    async fetchHealth() {
      const res = await fetch('api/health_parameters')

      const data = await res.json()

      return data


    },

    async fetchHealth(id){
      const res = await fetch(`api/health_parameters/${id}`)

      const data = await res.json()

      return data
    },
    

  },

 async created() {
    this.health_parameters = await this.fetchHealth()
  }
}
</script>

<style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: inherit;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

This is the vue.config.js that contains the proxy code

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '^/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:5000',
          changeOrigin: true,
          logLevel: 'debug',
          pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/' },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```

I honestly what to know what I am doing wrong. This is the error message I get.

The error is coming from this function

```
async fetchHealth(id){
          const res = await fetch(`api/health_parameters/${id}`)
    
          const data = await res.json()
    
          return data
        },
```

What do I do?

GET /health_parameters/undefined 404 3.189 ms - 2

Comment: `/api` is not `api/` - change your configuration to `^api` and report the result.

Comment: Still the same thing. Check the edited post please. The issue is with the the async fetchHealth(id) function

Comment: Fixed the error already. I was using the same function. fetcHealth() and fetchHealth(id). I changed the other one to fetchHealths(id)

Comment: I didn't see the second function with the same name. This is not Java - you cannot overload methods in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Coming from a Java background